# Populating a list box from the form in MS Access

Tags: vba, listbox, ms-access-2010

I have a form that I'm dynamically searching on.
I'm setting the filter on the form with some really nasty Like *' & {value} & *' OR Like (etc) parameters.

To my surprise, the filter actually runs quite quickly.  This is good.
However, the design that I've been lumped with dictates that I want to have a List Box that shows the customer name for all the customers that match the filtering.

Now, I know that Access already has this information, basically I just want the listbox to show the first column of what I'd see if I flicked to the datasheet view.

Sadly, the recommended way to do this seems to be to hit the database with my round trip query, and that's nasty and slow.

Is there any way to 'cheat' by reading the values out of the 'datasheet' for the form?

I tried assigning the recordset of the form to the recordset of the listbox, but Access didn't like that.

Comment: Looks like this does the trick

**`Set Me.ListN.Recordset = Me.Recordset`**

I wonder whether I should be using the RecordsetClone instead?

Answer (score 0):

When a filter is active on a form the form's `.RecordsetClone` object reflects the filtered set, so you should be able to use that to populate and re-populate the listbox. You will have to experiment a bit to find the "best" way to do that for your particular situation, but one approach would be to find a form event that fires at the required times (`On Current`, perhaps?) and use it to just clear out the listbox and use `.AddItem` to re-populate it as you loop through a copy of the RecordsetClone.